# Plotly Python - label value formatting

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

How can I format the label values so that it shows the actual decimals rather than automatically formatting to a micro unit?

E.g. Instead of 100µ I want it to show as 0.0001, no automatic formatting in the green label.

[image: See the green label]

**Update 12/2/18:**

Here's some samply data (macd_output variable):

```
                         macd  macdsignal      macdhist
datetime                                         
2018-02-12 19:44:00 -0.002401   -0.002316 -8.433693e-05
2018-02-12 19:45:00 -0.002353   -0.002325 -2.734004e-05
2018-02-12 19:46:00 -0.002107   -0.002271  1.641191e-04
2018-02-12 19:47:00 -0.002040   -0.002213  1.732582e-04
2018-02-12 19:48:00 -0.001814   -0.002113  2.990831e-04
2018-02-12 19:49:00 -0.001934   -0.002068  1.344275e-04
2018-02-12 19:50:00 -0.001814   -0.002005  1.910672e-04
2018-02-12 19:51:00 -0.002187   -0.002050 -1.370391e-04
2018-02-12 19:52:00 -0.002438   -0.002147 -2.903001e-04
2018-02-12 19:53:00 -0.003135   -0.002394 -7.411783e-04
2018-02-12 19:54:00 -0.003450   -0.002658 -7.918092e-04
2018-02-12 19:55:00 -0.003242   -0.002804 -4.379292e-04
2018-02-12 19:56:00 -0.003066   -0.002870 -1.962050e-04
2018-02-12 19:57:00 -0.003105   -0.002929 -1.769048e-04
2018-02-12 19:58:00 -0.002929   -0.002929 -6.099654e-07
```

Here's the python code portion for generating the plot:

```
...
macd_output = MACD(ohlcv,fastperiod=params['macd_parameters']['fast'], slowperiod=params['macd_parameters']['slow'], signalperiod=params['macd_parameters']['signal'])

print macd_output

macdhist = go.Bar(
    x=macd_output.index,
    y=macd_output.macdhist
)

macd = go.Scatter(
    x=macd_output.index,
    y=macd_output.macd
)

macdsignal = go.Scatter(
    x=macd_output.index,
    y=macd_output.macdsignal
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)

fig.append_trace(macdhist, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(macd, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(macdsignal, 1, 1)


update_dict = dict(
    xaxis = dict(
        rangeslider = dict(
            visible = False
        ),
        showgrid=True,
    )
)

print fig['layout'].update(update_dict)


plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

**Another Update:**

Thanks to anne's answer. This worked for me:

```
fig['layout']['yaxis1'].update(tickformat="0.5r")
```

Comment: Please provide some data and code.

Comment: Awesome, glad the input helped to figure it out.
Thanks for posting the final formatting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the flag from the d3 format:

```
d3.format("r")(0.0001)
```

> r - decimal notation, rounded to significant digits.

You can read more about it [here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/):

> tickformat (string)  default: ""
>   Sets the tick label formatting rule
>   using d3 formatting mini-languages which are very similar to those in
>   Python. 
>   For numbers, see:
>   https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format